# Is PEX piping more energy efficient than copper?

Tags: energy-efficiency, water-heating

My house has two bathrooms, with roughly the same distance of pipe from the water heater to each (see diagram below). One was added during a renovation and has [PEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linked_polyethylene) piping from the point where they diverge, while the other has copper piping all the way. When washing my hands, I've noticed that the water in the bathroom with PEX piping warms up much faster.

I suspect this is because the copper pipe conducts heat away faster than the the PEX pipe. At least [one website](https://energydiagnosticsinc.com/blog/pex-vs-copper-which-is-better-for-your-home/) supports this theory, but they don't provide any data:

> Water loses more heat while traveling through copper pipes, resulting in more energy use when compared to plastic piping.

Is this claim true, or could there be some other factor causing the water to warm up faster at the tap?

I am planning to renovate the other bathroom soon, and could replace the copper pipe with PEX in the process if there are energy efficiency benefits.

[image: Water piping diagram]

Comment: The copper has more thermal inertia as well, so it not only moves heat away from the water more efficiently, it takes more heat to warm the copper pipe up in the first place. The internal area of both pipes will also effect this - if the pipe holds more water you need to take more cold water out before it's full of hot water.

Comment: Sadly, "same distance as the person walks" and "same distance as the plumbing travels" are almost unrelated questions. You would need to trace the pipes to find out what the actual length is (in my house the "far" bathroom also has about twice as much pipe as the simple distance between points would suggest. It takes ~10 litres of water to empty that pipe... or fill it with hot water)

Comment: @Móż the piping distance is roughly the same -- I edited to clarify.

Comment: Are both plumbing runs insulated (or not insulated) the same way?

Comment: @Mark I added a diagram. The point where the plumbing diverges is where it goes into the wall, so I'm not able to add insulation after that. I know it's un-insulated because no other plumbing in the house was insulated when I moved in.

Comment: Perhaps define what you want 'energy efficient' to mean; transfer hot water with a minimum of energy loss to surroundings? Or more general? I.e. the pipes probably run within your house and as such deliver part of the hot water's energy to your houses which isn't necessarily a (complete) loss, if the pipes run in spaces which are heated through CV anyway?

Comment: I think the question is incomplete without a time frame; then it becomes "which will last longer , copper or plastic"?

Comment: @blacksmith37 either one should last at least 30 years. I don't expect to be living here that long, or if I do, the bathrooms will probably be renovated by then.